# Mysql loop and insert

Tags: mysql

I have the following MySql script:

```
SET @skip = 0;
SET @max = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE TempTable(
   id INT NOT NULL,
   name VARCHAR(32) NOT NULL
);

loop1: LOOP
  INSERT INTO TempTable (id, name) SELECT id, name FROM table1 LIMIT @skip, 1;

  IF @skip < @max THEN
    SET @skip = @skip + 1;
    ITERATE loop1;
  END IF;
  LEAVE loop1;
END LOOP loop1;

SELECT * FROM TempTable;
```

This script is not working but it should select all the id and names in `table1`. I am using a loop because I am also going to do other stuff in those loops but that is for later. 
I am not looking for a solution like `SELECT id, name FROM table1` but I want my error fixed. So I can continue with my loop.

The error I get is:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'loop1: LOOP   INSERT INTO TempTable (id, name) SELECT id, name
>   FROM table1' at line 1

Comment: I have no clue, I am trying to make this work, but I dont know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* a syntax error in your code (the `LIMIT @skip` which is dynamic SQL and requires some tricks to make it work) but it is not at `loop1: LOOP`.

My guess is you are trying to use LOOP outside a compound statement (`BEGIN` ... `END`) like a stored procedure, which is not possible. You have to create a stored procedure to do that.

Comment: That would most certainly be the case, is a transaction also ok to use a loop in?

Comment: No, on http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/sql-syntax-compound-statements.html it says: Stored procedures and functions, triggers, and events.

Answer (score 7):

```
/* set delimiter */
DELIMITER $$

/* remove procedure if exists... */
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS insert_it $$

/* create procedure */ 
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_it ()
BEGIN
DECLARE varcount INT DEFAULT 1;
DECLARE varmax INT DEFAULT 15;

WHILE varcount <= varmax DO
    INSERT INTO yourtable(fixed_val, count_val) VALUES(3493, varcount);
    SET varcount = varcount + 1;
END WHILE;

END $$

/* reset delimiter back to normal */
DELIMITER ;

/* call procedure */ 
CALL insert_it();
```

Comment: Code only answers are usually [frowned upon](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258673/2596334). Try adding an [explination or code comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/269981/2596334). Thanks.

Comment: While missing some explanation, I highly appreciated this A-Z solution - it worked out of the box.

Answer (score 6):

try something like this for the syntax of your loop:

```
DECLARE @count INT;
DECLARE @max INT;
SET @count=1;
SET @max= (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM table1);
WHILE(@count < @max)
BEGIN
    /*your database query logic*/
END
```

use "SET @count=(@count+1)" to increment your counter within the loop

Comment: This is a good solution. Why do you explicitly use user variables here?